# Getting data from a website that needs you to log in (Java)

Tags: java, https, web-crawler, web-scraping

I don't even know if what I'm asking is possible and I don't know what to search for on Google.

Basically, there are multiple projects that would require me to fetch some data from websites. The example I'm thinking of right now is to grab my account info from a banking site http://www.americanexpress.ca I'd like to know how I'd make it so my login info is entered in the fields on the left and grab the data from the resulting page. I'd then make methods to parse that data.

Obviously, this would need to be secure as I don't want my banking info stolen.

Sorry if the solution is obvious as I've never tried grabbing data from websites.

Comment: The term to search for is "web scraping"

Comment: Thank you! Will that let me enter the login credentials and grab the data inside nested links?

Comment: Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can be very effective in debugging network messages passed between your browser and an SSL encrypted website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, Apache HttpClient is one option, though personally I've always found [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to be a bit more convenient to work with (from an API standpoint) for doing things like this.  HtmlUnit is built on top of HttpClient, and exposes a higher-level API for interacting with and manipulating page content.

Comment: @Adam - Yes.  If you point it at a secure URL then the connection will use SSL.  It is just as secure as going through a regular web browser would be.

Comment: I agree that HtmlUnit is more convenient for automating "user-like" activity, but it is worth noting that HttpClient got a heck of a lot better in the last major release. I'd also toss out Watir and Selenium as solid choices; Selenium is especially great for not-very-technical people.

Comment: I took a quick look at the HTMLUnit doc and it seems great. Thanks for the input. I might also take a look at the alternatives

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) (or same) library. It have all required classes for you.